# AWS S3 – allow user to only access his files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to add an image upload possibility for my users.
So far I've followed a simple YouTube tutorial and created a new bucket with the following `Bucket policy`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1578265217545",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "statement-1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/images/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following `CORS policy`:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

I've also created an IAM user, and attached the following policy to it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Delete*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I got my access and secret keys that I successfully used to upload/delete files – success.

I have a strong feeling, the above policies are not really secure at this moment (e.g. I'm planning to make the CORS policy more strict, by only allowing the bucket to be accessed from a certain domain).

My main question now is – How can I make sure that if user A uploads his image, no other user (until allowed) can access it?

Comment: this is a really broad topic / question. but you need to put an api of some sort in front of it that tracks who has access to what and grants access to files accordingly.

Comment: @bryan60 I was afraid this would be probably the best answer for this. I have a nodeJS-based API for the app, and I've installed `multer` to do the uploads. Do you have any good reads to recommend for this particular scenario?

Comment: im sure there are plenty of guides. i mostly do this using signed urls though.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be possible if each user of the application has an IAM user account in AWS. Then you could have restrict the images using the corresponding AWS IAM user. But I believe this is probably not the case.

Something better would be, instead of accessing the images directly on AWS, access the images via your application. You could have a table storing the image path in the bucket on AWS, the corresponding owner(s) and also a flag indicating if the image can be accessed publicly or not.

Then when you need a specific image, you would make a request to your application, which would check if the user making the request is the owner of the image, if yes, the application would **download** the image from AWS using the [AWS S3 SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) and send it over to the user.

This approach will decouple AWS from your end users and your app will be responsible for managing who can access what. Given every request to AWS will pass through your app, there is less risk on compromising the AWS infrastructure in place.

Comment: This is my current approach, my this does not prevent from an abusive user to potentially access the image by directly typing in the image URL (yet I'm trying to make them as hard to guess as possible).

Comment: In the approach I described, you are not returning the URL of the image, instead, the application is serving the image itself as a stream of bytes or anything that seems fit. The bucket can be made private as well, because you won't be accessing anything publicly; the app will use the AWS SDK to access the bucket and the images. So there is not URL guessing and spamming.

Answer (score 2):

Object tagging and attribute-based access control could be used for conditional access to different objects.

Use case: Application not supporting individual IAM users:

- Objects are assigned ownerID tag with id value,
- Users are assigned an uuid or their profile has a tag with some kind of id value and
- API function used to fetch objects compares object tag and user id/tag and retrieves only objects with matching values

Use case: Application supporting AWS IAM users / SSO users:

- Objects are assigned a tag with appropriate value (id,
  department, etc),
- AWS users are assigned a tag with appropriate value
  (id, department etc.),
- An IAM role and an access control policy are
  created for allowing conditional access depending on tag values

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/tagging-and-policies.html